# Lock on an object and change its field. Does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

If I write a class like this:

```
public class LockBool
{
    public bool validity = true;
}
```

And then I lock on such an object and change its `validity` field:

```
LockBool lockObj = GetTheLockObject();
lock(lockObj)
{
    //release some resources
    lockObj.validity = false;
}
```

So if another thread locks on the same object, it can read the `validity` for flow control.

```
lock(lockObj)
{
    if(!validity)
        return;
    //do something here
}
```

Does it work as I expect, without throwing exception?

(If it works but it's bad practice, I also would like to know the details. Thanks!)

P.S.: The reason I tried to use the type with a bool field is to create variable number of lock objects. And it seems difficult to prevent other threads from acquiring the lock after I release resources. So a bool field can tell a thread if this lock is still valid, or it should be garbage-collected.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question. What do you mean by *Does it work as I expect?* What do you expect?

Comment: Please see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I wonder if `lockObj` still locks the critical section without any exception and the `validity` value can be used by other threads to do flow control. Sorry if it's unclear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/lockchoice.shtml).

using this kind of locking is discouraged, usually you should define a simple object varibale  like

```
private static readonly object _lock;
```

with this kind of lock object you can sync between instances of your class (because it is static and shared between all instances) and no one can change its value (because it is readonly) and no one can use a lock on it from outside of class and make things go wrong (because it is private)

and if you want to just make the object thread safe (not all objects that are instantiated) you can remove the static and just use as many private object as you should.

**UPDATE base on your comment**

you can define a class like this

```
public class LockWrapper<T>
{
    public T InsideClass { get; set; }
    public readonly object _lock;
}
```

then use this when you need multiple instance of some class and want to lock on them separately

Comment: I know you are right. It's just sometimes I need variable number of lock objects to manage resources (like multiple sockets or multiple files), so I always wonder if there is an easy solution. Yeah maybe I should just declare several `static readonly` objects, like a pool.